# jQuery DataTable plugin loses data

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable

I'm using the jQuery DataTable plugin in one of my projects and having hard time configuring it.

I'm using this data-table plugin for sorting purposes only, so the other options are disabled.

The table is being generated via a callback function of a web-service. Web-service makes the call and returns a JSON object. I'm parsing that JSON and constructing the table rows, then initializing the DataTable on that table as follows:

```
$('.table').each(function() {
     $(this).DataTable({
         "paging": false,
         "searching": false,
         "info" : false
      });
});
```

The problem is that the table contents may be updated without page reload and I have to re-initialize the table each time a new table is being created.

The thing is that when I initialize the table in the aforementioned way, the plugin gives me an error alert which refers to problem of re-initialization. So I found out I need to first destroy the old table object using the following property:

"destroy": true

The initialization code will now look as follows:

```
$('[data-ride="datatables"]').each(function() {
     $(this).DataTable({
         "paging": false,
         "searching": false,
         "info" : false,
         "destroy": true
      });
});
```

However now the plugin loses some rows which have to be there. If I disable the DataTable plugin - all the rows are correct and some of them get lost when I enable it.

Could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did I get that correctly, that you have multiple tables that you create in HTML from the returned JSON, afterwards initialize as data tables and maybe update their data by repeating those steps? If yes, then it should help to use the data tables API to clear and add the new data instead of creating them newly and adding data through HTML. That way the whole data handling is a lot cleaner and any errors that would still show up much easier to track down and fix.